# winrar and "put authenticity verification"?

Tags: windows, winrar

When should I check this checkbox ?

[image]

and If i'm about to open a rar , how can I see the authenticity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After open the rar archive with winrar press alt+i (extras -> get information).
It shows stats about the archive and if available, the info about package creator.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the [options page](http://www.winrar-tr.com/WinRAR/Help/ENG/html/HELPExtractAdvOptions.htm) are winRar:

> Check the information about creator of RAR archive added by "Put authenticity verification" > option in General part of archiving dialog. Turning this option off can save some time when > unpacking large RAR archives.

From another website:

> This option enables WinRAR to stamp the archive with specific credentials such as
>   creator name, date created, and last updated. This allows anyone who has your file
>   to check and verify no one else has made any modifications.

Only turn this option on if you want others to be able to check that **you** make this archive and nobody tampered with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since RAR verion 5, this feature has been removed, see http://www.rarlab.com/rarnew.htm

> 8. Features removed:
>
>    a) authenticity verification feature did not provide the required
>          level of reliability and was removed;

Comment: This does not really answer the question. You should post it as a comment.